# Inset Grouped UITableView with Header Section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I have Used `UITableView` with Two prototype Cells and **Inset Grouped** style

[image]

Without `viewForHeaderInSection` Output will be fine

[image]

After Add `viewForHeaderInSection` Output will be Like this

[image]

Expected Output

[image]

**Here is my code**

```
extension DashboardVC:UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 4
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 45
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 70
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TblHeaderCell") as! TblHeaderCell
        return headerCell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TblSectionCell", for: indexPath) as! TblSectionCell
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: I am facing the same situation. Header and footer views have left margin like 16px, I want to make 0px margins. Any idea to solve left margins?

Comment: did you get solution to this issue? I m using custom headerviews and facing the exact issue of alignment.

Answer (score 4):

First, **Inset Grouped** tableView's have additional alignment properties...

If you use default cells and simply set the `titleForHeaderInSection`, you'll see that the text in the section header is aligned with the text in the cell.

In addition, **Inset Grouped** rounds the corners of the *section of rows* -- it does NOT include the section header.

Here's how it looks with a plain `UIView` as the section header view:

[image]

Zoomed in a little:

[image]

To get the visual output you're going for, I think you'll want to use your "header cell" as the first row in the section, and your "section cell" for the remaining rows:

[image]

I'm guessing the "down arrow / chevron" in your section header indicates you want to expand / collapse the sections? If so, you'll need to refactor your code to display only the first row when the section is collapsed.

Another option would be to NOT use **Inset Grouped**, and instead customize your cells to round the top corners of the section header and bottom corners of only the last cell in the section ... or round all 4 corners of the header when the section is collapsed.

Comment: I already know about how to do it manually I just want to know how I can do it directly with **Inset Grouped** property

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani - this solution *is* using **Inset Grouped**. My point is that you cannot get your design using section headers, as **Inset Grouped** rounds the corners of the section and leaves the header as a non-rounded rectangle.

Comment: @DonMag if the header view are custom, then how to solve the alignment issue?